# Zero average function density

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

How can we prove that the space $V = \{ v \in {H^1}(0,L),\int\limits_0^L {v(x)dx = 0} \} $ is dense in ${L^2}(0,L)$ ?  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not.

Since $v \mapsto \int_0^L v$ is a bounded functional on $L^2(0,L)$, its kernel $K = \{ v \in L^2(0,L): \int_0^L v = 0 \}$ is a closed proper subspace of $L^2(0,L)$. On the other hand $V \subseteq K$ and hence $V$ cannot be dense in $L^2(0,L)$.

Comment: Can it be dense in  $ H^1 $   ?  Thank you  ....

Comment: No, $V$ is a closed proper subspace of $H^1$. The same argument (with $L^2$ replaced by $H^1$) applies.